# Core module descriptions or overviews

Tags: module, magento-1

I'm going through a newly created site and am trying to deactivate all the modules that I won't need. I'm familiar enough with some of them to know what effect turning them off will have, but with others I end up having to poke around the module's code for a while to get a feel for what it does.

Is there any existing documentation for the core modules that gives a general overview of what each module does? (Eg. `Mage_Wishlist`: Allows logged in users to save a list of items with their account that can be added to the cart at a later time.)

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options, instead of poking around the code, you can poke around the generated documentation for the code ...

http://docs.magentocommerce.com/

Also of course, there is the user guide ...

http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/magento-user-guide

However, if you are looking for an all in one, or in-depth magento docs, you're going to need to speak with Chuck Norris, he is the only one with full magento documentation...

https://www.facebook.com/TRICsolutions/posts/284923624886069

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm aware of first two links. Link three warrants some serious study. However, I'm looking for documentation that is more narrowly focused on a description of what each module does and when it's needed. Even getting some updates to the <depends> nodes would be great. 

I ran into a bunch of issues in a fresh install of EE 1.13, Where, for example, disabling Mage_Newsletter causes a fatal error when trying to save a customer.